# Laravel sends the server on 10 redirects?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

Getting error message:

```
[Sun Jun 02 12:43:33.579095 2013] [core:error] [pid 4964:tid 808] [client 127.0.0.1:56964] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a
```

When trying to use laravel to do routing. My routes are as follows:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('history', 'HistoryController@showHistory');
```

And my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my alias:

```
Alias /wunhopkuendo/ "c:/wamp/www/wunhopkuendo/public/" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/wunhopkuendo/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does this happen also when you have no routes defined?

Comment: Adjust the `LogLevel` to see where it's internally redirecting you.

Comment: check your virtual host configuration. The path to the public folder might not be the one you think.

Answer (score 37):

I had this problem as well, and I solved it with the following line on the **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Laravel in a subfolder, you need to follow these steps:

Assuming that you use WAMP with the default installation directory (i.e. `c:\wamp`)

Insert the RewriteBase line in your .htaccess file with the subfolder of your Laravel instalation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
<IfModule>
```

Set the application URL on file `c:\wamp\www\subfolder\config\app.php`

```
'url' => 'http://localhost/subfolder',
```

Create a configuration file on alias directory `c:\wamp\alias\subfolder.conf`  with this content:

```
Alias /subfolder "c:/wamp/www/testando/public"

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/subfolder/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: what is this `hggp`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your public folder is setup properly

Answer (score 0):

In my case the .htaccess in public folder was missing because of that it was throwing this redirect error. Make sure that your "public/.htaccess" file is available. Hope its helps.